# Не очищается Remote BLOB Storage (Filestream) от устаревших файлов после CHECKPOINT

Tags: sql, filestream, sharepoint

Всем привет!
Имеется SharePoint 2010 на SQL для базы контента настроен RBS, ранее без проблем чистил путем запуска Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.Maintainer и после выполнял CHECKPOINT для БД, "устаревшие" файлы при этом без проблем удалялись. Сейчас по какой-то неведомой причине указанные выше манипуляции ни к чему не приводят, место на диске не высвобождается. Уже прошерстил кучу форумов по данному вопросу, но ничего не помогает. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Помимо чистки [Remote Blob storage](http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/remote-blob-storage-rbs/) 
используйте SHRINK

[How to shrink SQL / SharePoint database / log files](https://www.satheesh.net/2011/04/05/how-to-shrink-sql-sharepoint-database-log-files/)